# Is there a way to write Postman tests using a plain Assert instead of Chai BDD?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

Postman test examples all use the Chai BDD library. Personally I think BDD style testing libraries that attempt to imitate natural language are a fundamentally bad idea. In Chai there are different accessor properties for `eq`, `eql`, `equal` and `equals`. There is also `be` which it seems can be used with all of these.

I don't want to spend any of my life working out the difference between

`expect(something).to.eq(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.eql(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.equal(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.equals(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.be.eq(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.be.eql(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.be.equal(something-else)`

`expect(something).to.be.equals(something-else)`

I would much rather just have

`assert(something, 'message')`

How can I most effectively do this in Postman?